# Update data through Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have the below code on href click I'm calling a javascript code in which an ajax is being called which returns the value of array `$ss` in json format . Now I want to know how can I update the value of $ss via ajax.

```
 <div class="white" id="white" style="display:none">   
        <?php
            foreach ($ss as $key => $value){
        ?>
        <a  href='javascript:void(0);'  onclick='callAjax('<?php echo $key; ?>')'>
        <?php   
           echo $value;
        ?>
        </a>
        <?php
           }
        ?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var res;
        function on(id){
            //alert('hi '+id);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php', //This is the current doc
                type: "GET",
                data: ({a: id }),
                success: function(data){
                    res = data;
                    //alert(res);
                    document.write(res);
                }
            }); 

        }

    </script>
```

And ajax.php files return array values for $ss.
I understood how to update data of normal div through ajax but encountering problem to pass the data returned by ajax call to update array value.

Comment: And why you want it so??

Comment: becoz that's what I want to do.......REQUIRNMENT

Comment: ok so what is the next step. What do you want to do IF you update the array?

Comment: You can't. `$ss` is rendered on page load by the server. Then there is no `$ss`. You can create the html after you receive the data. Or you can take advantage of two way data binding features from vue.js or other libraries. You may take a look on https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/list.html if you are interested on two way data binding. Or just create the html and replace it.

Comment: right now I want to update the array then regenerate the html code for this portion.

Comment: Then store the value of your `$ss` in a javascript array on page load and update this array on ajax call sucess. You cannot update a php variable in javascript

Comment: i don't want to load page again . i want that on click of anchor tag the data related to that comes from database  through ajax without page reload

Comment: I am not saying to load again. I am saying to store the value of php variable `$ss`  in a javascript array, when your page is loaded for the first time. And then when you  make the ajax call update this javascript variable with the newly returned values from ajax

Answer (score 1):

**1-** Lets be clear javascript will not replace the content of a php variable.
 **2-** Even if so you will not be able to regenerate the html you need this way.
**3-** after you receive your variable you need to update the html instead.

**PS:** Surely you can update the variable on the `server` side when you receive that `ajax` call,
that also needs some requirements(**the variable is global and accessible inside the php file...**),
but from what I have understood you want to change it with javascript which is not possible.

Comment: I just need to update the variable rest I'll regenerate the html

Comment: is there any way around .I can't find any

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax must like this...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var res;
        function on(id){
            //alert('hi '+id);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php', //This is the current doc
                type: "GET",
                data: {a: id },
                success: function(data){
                    res = data;
                    //alert(res);
                    document.write(res);
                }
            }); 

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: can you post ajax.php for further help

Comment: that includes mysql queries only

Comment: data: {a: id }, see here

Comment: see console.log(data) what  is output?

Comment: @HikmatSijapati can you please explain what you have done ?

Comment: but what the effect of this ??output is same as previous

Comment: just cosole your data and replace your div.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't.

PHP code is run server-side, and jQuery runs on the client. The way to update a PHP variable from jQuery is to have a jQuery call which submits to the PHP page, and have the PHP look for it.

```
$ss = 'ss value';  
if exists($_POST['ss']) {
   $ss = $_POST['ss'];
}
```